# Как правильно добавить события к динамически создаваемым элементам?

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, javascript, html, css

Исользую jquery. Мне нужно сделать, чтобы при наведении на любую ссылку в документе, отображалось бы - `alert("ссылка")`.
Изначально, в документе, у меня уже есть одна ссылка - `<a>Первая</a>`. Для неё я при загрузке добавляю событие - `$("a").hover(function(e) {alert("ссылка"); })`. Далее при наведение на эту ссылку событие отрабатывает нормально. Но после добавлении ссылок динамически (событие -  `$("a").click`) на новых ссылках событие не срабатывает.

Код страницы:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Nexus</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jq.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

        $("a").click(function(e) {
            $("body").append("<a>Остальные</a>");
        })
        $("a").hover(function(e) {alert("ссылка"); });      
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a>Первая</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы событие `$("a").hover` отрабатывало на все ссылки, в том числе и динамически, в том числе и на добавленные после загрузки документа?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[[@vvtvvtvvt](/users/14942/vvtvvtvvt)](/users/14942/vvtvvtvvt), по сути, вам уже ответил [[@artem328](/users/19340/artem328)](/users/19340/artem328), но только он почему-то поленился рассказать, что для динамических элементов используется делегированная обработка собятий, и схематически это выглядит так:

```
$('parent_static').on('event', 'children_dinamic', handler);
```

Где **parent_static** - это статичный родительский элемент (*лучше ближайший, но подойдёт и body*), **event** - событие, **children_dinamic** - дочерний динамический элемент, на котором обработчик и должен сработать. При этом указатель **this** или объект jQuery **$(this)** в обработчике - имено дочерний динамический элемент.

Comment: Спасибо. Работает.

Comment: Большое спасибо Вам. Так долго искал эту проблему в своём проекте..

Answer (score 1):

[Вот как-то так](http://jsfiddle.net/5g7r4mhq/)

Answer (score -6):

Вы привязываете события к ссылкам только при загрузке страницы, когда только одна ссылка существует.  Решением будет привязывать события каждый раз, когда добавляется ссылка.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Nexus</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jq.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function clck(){
        $("body").append('<a onclick="clck()" onmouseover="hover()">Остальные</a>');
       }    
       function hover(){        
        alert("ссылка");    
       }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a onclick="clck()" onmouseover="hover()">Первая</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nssLr11m/)

Comment: nicael, Я пробовал такой вариант - он те подходит. С ним, при каждом событие кол-во событий увеличивается. Т.е. Например при нажатие первый раз на ссылку "Первая" добавляется одна ссылка, при нажатии второй раз добавляется уже сразу две ссылки, в третий 3 и т.д. Тоже самое и выводом ссобщений

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt Вы правы. Проверьте новую версию.

Comment: Что не так теперь? Почему минусы? Всё работает...

Comment: @nicael, в этом веке пользоваться onclick уже не стоит.

Comment: @Etki Почему не стоит? onclick ни разу не устаревший.

Comment: @nicael, W3C [The evolution of events][1]. Да и вообще, говоря об устаревшем или нет, то ereg_replace (*в PHP*) тоже замечательно себя чувствует, если у вас версия php 5.2. Но мы ведь в каком веке живём?

   [1]:http://www.w3.org/wiki/Handling_events_with_JavaScript#The_evolution_of_events